# Can't get childs from listview without clicking on item

Tags: android, listview

I'm having trouble getting my animations to work within my ListView. I can get items to animate when I click on them, but I am trying to get the items that I have not just clicked on to animate as well.

I thought I might get the second animation to simply start after first, but then even after making the ListView final the getChildAt and getChildCount return null and 0 respectively anywhere else I call them in the code, even if I send the views from the click to another method.

I repeat, getChildAt() simply returns null everywhere else in my code unless I call another touch command.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, final View v, int position, long id) {

    int count = l.getChildCount();
    int one = l.getLastVisiblePosition();
    int two = l.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    Message.message(this, one+" and " +two);
    Message.message(this, ""+count);

    v.setHasTransientState(true);
    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, View.TRANSLATION_X, 0, 100);
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            swipeOnDoneButtonClick(v);
            View first = l.getChildAt(0);
            first.setHasTransientState(true);
            ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(first, View.TRANSLATION_X, 0, 100);
            animator.setDuration(1000);
            animator.start();
        }
    });
    anim.start();



}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

implements OnScrollListener

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnScrollListener {
```

and set OnScrollListener in listView

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(MainActivity.this);
```

and you can get first and last visible rows

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    firstVisibleRow = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            lastVisibleRow = listView.getLastVisiblePosition();
```

/*Now you get the first and last visible rows, and you easily get the rows from first to last visible row and appy animation to the visible rows..,.*/
}

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}
```

code in onScroll

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    int firstVisibleRow = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    int lastVisibleRow = listView.getLastVisiblePosition();

    for(int i=firstVisibleRow;i<=lastVisibleRow;i++)
    {
        //Write your code here(allocation/deallocation/store in array etc.)
        System.out.println(i + "=" + listView.getItemAtPosition(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I call the onScroll when I update the ListAdapter? I've never used onScroll before so I'm not sure how to make it only get called when I want it to. I ask because my question was to avoid clicking in order to call an animation.